# How to run specific functions from PHP file using JS

Tags: javascript, php

I did my best to find the answer but am still stucked. Beginner in PHP here. 
I know I can call my php file from my js code using either a xmlhttprequest or ajax.

Let's say I have various classes and functions in my php file and I want to run "nameColor" function with my js code.

```
public function nameColor($playerlvl, $monsterlvl) {
      if ($playerlvl === $monsterlvl) {
        $this->colorToPlayer = "white";
      } else if ($playerlvl < $monsterlvl) {
        $this->colorToPlayer = "red";
      } else if ($playerlvl > $monsterlvl) {
        $this->colorToPlayer = "blue";
      }
    }
```

So I need to set attributs for my function and run it to get a result. How do I proceed in js please?

My js code is just (calling my PHP file and appending some data to html page):

```
<script>
function getInfoPHP () {
    $.ajax({
      url:"l2charcreation.php", //the page containing php script
      type: "GET",
      success:function(result){
      $('.newCharacterInfo').append(result);
     }
   });
}

</script>
```

Comment: Show us your JS code so far

Comment: AJAX is the way to proceed.

Comment: Added my small js, I use ajax to call the php file but can't figure out how to run function of my choice with choosen attributs...

Answer (score 0):

You can add data to your ajax like this:

```
function getInfoPHP () {
    $.ajax({
      url:"l2charcreation.php", //the page containing php script
      type: "GET",
      data: {func: 'getColor', attr1: '5', attr2: '4'},
      success:function(result){
      $('.newCharacterInfo').append(result);
     }
   });
}
```

and then in l2charcreation.php you have to switch between your functions based on the value of `$_GET['func']` and provide them attributes from `$_GET['attr1']` and so on. After that you need to echo the result in php and you will receive it in your js. Simplified example:

```
function foo($a1) {
    echo 'processed foo'.$a1;
}

function bar() {
    echo 'processed bar';
}

switch($_GET['func']) {
case 'foo':
    foo($_GET['attr1']);
    break;
case 'bar':
    bar();
    break;
default :
    echo 'function not found';
}
```

---

The general idea is something like this:
Lets say you have only two files:

- `index.html` (one containing your js)
- `l2charcreation.php` (one with a lot of php functions)

And you want to access data generated by a specific php function in `l2charcreation.php` from js in `index.html`.
So you use ajax function in js - it connects to the server in background and asks for `l2charcreation.php` with the name of the function and it's arguments specified (in GET or POST). Server responds similarly to how it would respond to a browser accessing this file, so if you want to pass some data to js in `index.html` you need to echo it in `l2charcreation.php`.

Comment: I didn't understand that part "you have to switch between your functions based on the value of $_GET['func'] and provide them attributes from $_GET['attr1'] and so on". Could you show with code please? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does is suppose to work when my functions are inside classes as I try to do this in OOP? Shouldn't I initiate an new object before calling the function as I would have done inside PHP? How to do so?

Comment: I've edited the answer. It doesn't really matter if your php is object oriented or not, you have to echo your data either way.